# See number of SVN Checkins per folder

Tags: svn

I have a very large SVN repository (working copy of several gb) that has just reached its 20,000th checkin. As a bit of an interesting statistic for our team (and to partly celebrate our 20,000th checkin) I'd like to make a graph showing which folders in the repository have had the most checkins.

Is there any way to do this? We mostly use integrated SVN clients in our IDE and Tortoise SVN, but I'm willing to get other tools for this one-off thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run

> svn log *<directory>* | grep '^r' | wc -l

To run this for every single folder inside a working copy and get a CSV as the output:

> find *<directory>* ( ! -regex '.*/..*' ) -type d -exec /bin/bash -v
>   -c "echo -n \"{},\";svn log \"{}\"|grep '^r'| wc -l" > ./SVNLog.txt \;

Comment: @Farseeker: nice edit - you deserve at least half the credit for this answer